# Elastic Search 6.0 from/size not work, get duplicate

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search. I'm trying to get all the data between a time window. The result size is 10 by default. Is there any way to get all data with multiple query or within one query?

This is the query I use

```
query={
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 30,
  "query":{
    "range":{
     "created_at":{
          "gte":"2010-01-27T02:47:19",
          "lte":"2010-01-27T23:16:59",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

As the result data must be larger than 30. I think using from to multiple query data.
After the first time search, I will do a second one, like this:

```
query={
  "from" : 1,
  "size" : 30,
  "query":{
    "range":{
     "created_at":{
          "gte":"2010-01-27T02:47:19",
          "lte":"2010-01-27T23:16:59",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. The response from the second query return all almost the same data as the first one.

Could anyone tell me what's the problem?

I'm using ElasticSearch Python lib.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The `"from" : n` tells ES to return results starting the nth place in the index. So 1 shouldn't matter much. You don't need it in your case

Comment: I'm trying to get all the result from a query. The result size is 10 by default. How could I get the total items?

Comment: I you do a query, the total number of items is returned in the response. Make a query, get the total number, replace that in size (leave from as is)

Comment: You, should always apply sorting while doing pagination,or use scroll query

Answer (score 2):

From/size is designed for [search results pagination](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html), to fetch next 30 you have to do `from=30&size=30`. `from` is an offset, i.e. position of the first document to be fetched.

In your case the first query fetched results from 0 to 29, and the second from 1 to 30, and as you can see all but one of them are duplicate.

Hope that helps!